# Grunt - Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Just started trying to set up Grunt but hit an issue straight away.

```
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Or in full:

```
>> Error: Unable to parse "package.json" file (Unexpected token c).
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I am following this guide: http://24ways.org/2013/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/

And the two files are:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "BuildSanctuary",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// 1. All configuration goes here 
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        concat: {
             dist: {
                 src: [
                     'public_html/js/*.js', // All JS in the libs folder
                 ],
                 dest: 'public_html/js/production.js',
             }
        }

});

// 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

// 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I saved the file as a UTF-8 and it worked fine.

Comment: I hardly doubt it was related to the encoding of the code you've pasted above! The error says "`(Unexpected token c).`" there must have been the character "`c`" somewhere outside the string or something completely non-JSON in the whole file.

Comment: I searched around and found someone else had the same issue. A suggestion elsewhere said to save the file as UTF-8 since the standard encoding adds something extra... Its out of my scope if im honest. But changing the save type fixed it.

Comment: What encoding was it before? This would be quite helpful in your answer (for others with the same problem). :)

Answer (score 0):

saving the file in UTF-8 will help.
Just go to the text editor in my case its sublime text.

File -> Save with Encoding -> UTF-8

grunt was able to find the default task.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by installing grunt-cli, I only had grunt installed and was running into this same error.

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-cli
```

Edit:
The above just got me closer to the problem. I was running into other missing packages is all. Once I got them all installed it worked.